# I cant install libraries?

Tags: python, installation, pip

I wanted to install scipy through pip and it outputted this:

```
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\users\ejrgo\scoop\apps\python\current\lib\site-packages (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<1.29.0,>=1.22.4 in c:\users\ejrgo\scoop\apps\python\current\lib\site-packages (from scipy) (1.26.4)
```

I haven't tried to install it before, but i did try to install manim the other day, which looked like it worked but VScode gave me an error when i ran some code from it. When i was trying to install manim it lloked like it installed scipy along with it so that may be messing things up abit. but if anyone could help me get manim aswell that would be really helpful too.

Comment: The message is telling you that it is already installed.

Comment: what gives you the impression its not yet installed?

Answer (score 0):

The Output "Requirement already satisfied" implies that the desired package is already installed.

try:

```
pip list
```

to list all installed packages. Check if scipy is listed there.

Comment: it is installed but when i import it i get an import error saying module not found

Comment: how does your import statement look like?

Comment: is scipy listed when you pip list?

Comment: 'from scipy import constants' scipy is underlined in yellow if that helps

Comment: yeah it shows up when i pip list

Comment: thats odd your statement looks correct

Comment: import scipy

print(scipy.__version__) What happens if you do this?